# Atribuindo valor de um image(s) no input Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Eu tenho o seguinte input

```
<input type="file" id="imagefiles" name="files[]" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none;" />
```

Este input recebe até 3 imagens

Eu estou usando o javascript para dar um post dessa forma `'Imagem': $('#imagefiles').val(),` mas nesse caso ele pega apenas a da primeira imagem, como estou usando `files[]` gostaria de sabem como faço para acessar as 3 posições do vetor e atribuir no javascript.

Agradicmento @MagicHat por ter me ajudado na questão passada, me disponibilizou o codigo para o upload das imagens , segue o codigo que estou usando :

```
 var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect");
var fileElem = document.getElementById("imagefiles");



fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    fileSelect.style.cssFloat = "top";
    fileSelect.style.marginRight = "10px";
    fileSelect.style.marginTop = "-3px";
    if (fileElem) {
        fileElem.click();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}
, false);

function handleFileSelect(evt) {

    var list = document.getElementById("list").childElementCount;
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var qtde = files.length;
    var nomes = fileElem.files;
    var nome;

    if (qtde > 3 || list > 2) {
        alert('Erro! Número máximo de fotos é 3 !');
        document.getElementById('imagefiles').value = "";
        return;
    } else {
        for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
            if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
                continue;
            }
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = (function (theFile) {
                return function (e) {
                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.innerHTML =
'<div class="col-lg-4">' + "<a href='#'><img style='float:left;padding: 1px;height: 155px; margin-right:15px; width: 155px;border: 5px solid #c7c7c7;margin-top: 0px;' src='" + e.target.result + "'" + "title='" + escape(theFile.name) + "'/>" + '<img src="/Content/imagens/principais/close-button.png" style="height: 15px; width: 15px; margin-right:5px;">' + "  </a></div>";
                    document.getElementById('list').insertBefore(span, null);
                    span.children[0].addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
                        span.parentNode.removeChild(span);
                    });
                };
            })(f);
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
document.getElementById('imagefiles').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

EDIT : a parte completa do input :

```
<legend class="leg_img">Insira imagens</legend>
                <fieldset id="upload_img" class="nf_class upload_img">
                    <input type="file" id="imagefiles" name="files[]" multiple accept="image/*" style="display:none;" />
                    <a href="#" id="fileSelect" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px">selecionar imagens</a>
                    <div id="list" style="margin-bottom:0;"></div>
                </fieldset>
```

EDIT 2 : Post :

```
 $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
    NovaPublicacao();
})

function NovaPublicacao() {
    var produtoData = {

        'Titulo': $('#produtoTitulo').val(),
        'Descricao': $('#produtoDescricao').val(),
        'Imagem': $('#imagefiles').val()

        // adicionando valores as variáveis
    };
    console.log(produtoData);

    $("#disableModal").addClass("disabledbutton"), // disabilita a pagina
    $('#loadingModal').show(); // Adiciona o Loading
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Produto/Publicar", //altere para o caminho que você vai querer mandar o post
        type: "post", //tipo post
        data: produtoData, //os dados
        success: function (json) { //em caso de  sucesso faça
            if (json.isRedirect) {
                window.location.href = json.redirectUrl;
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {//em caso de erro faça
            console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT 3 : Vou explicar um pouco da situação do Backend, esses metódos não fui eu quem fiz, mas como eles não server mas para o modelo do Administrador, porque eles subiam apenas 1 foto, eu terei que altera-ló, mas ainda não sei como passar as informações necessarias para ele, então nem alterei ele ainda .

```
  public JsonResult CriarPublica(string ProdutoId, HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile)
    {
        if (Web.Utils.Util.ExtensaoPermitidaImagem(Path.GetExtension(uploadFile.FileName.ToLower())))
        {
            int idProduto = Convert.ToInt32(SystemCriptografia.ToDescriptografaQueryString(ProdutoId));
            var produto = ProdutoServico.GetById(idProduto);
            if (produto == null)
                return Json(new { Erro = true, Msg = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSG_ERRO_DADOS"] });
            int qntofotos = this.FotoProdutoServico.GetMany(p => p.ProdutoId == idProduto).Count();
            if (qntofotos == produto.Loja.QntMaxFotosProduto)
            {
                return Json(new { Erro = true, Msg = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSG_NUMERO_MAXIMO_FOTOS"] });
            }

            string NomeImagem = uploadFile.FileName.ToLower();
            string ExtensaoImagem = Path.GetExtension(uploadFile.FileName.ToLower());
            FotoProduto foto = new FotoProduto(idProduto, NomeImagem, ExtensaoImagem);

            this.FotoProdutoServico.Add(foto);

            int dimensao = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TAMANHO_FOTO_PRODUTO"]);
            Image i = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Web.Utils.Util.RedimensionarImagem(uploadFile.InputStream, dimensao)));
            ProdutoServico.SalvarArquivoProduto(i, foto);

            //-----INSERÇÃO NO MODELO ANTIGO!
            produto.NomeImagem = produto.ProdutoId.ToString();
            produto.Extensao = ExtensaoImagem;
            this.ProdutoServico.Update(produto);

            Image f = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(Web.Utils.Util.RedimensionarImagem(uploadFile.InputStream, dimensao)));
            ProdutoServico.SalvarArquivos(i, produto);
            //-----------------------


            return Json(new { Atualizar = true, Msg = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSG_IMG_ENVIADA"] });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new { Erro = true, Msg = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MSG_ERRO_EXTENSAO_IMAGEM"] });
        }
    }

}
```

OBS. Na verdade possui mais um metodo mais ainda estou analisando esses metodos backend, talvez irei mudalos por completo.

Comment: Coloca a parte do POST, no seu código, o que vc está tentando.

Comment: Nossa nem reparei que não tinha colocado a parte completa , um segundo.

Comment: O que acha de trocar o termo "vetor" para "imagem(s)"?

Comment: Troquei, se você acha que fica melhor... =] 
Aguardando...

Comment: Você também pode mostrar o código ao lado do servidor, com certeza vamos precisar modificar ele

Comment: Vou postar sim, mas não tenho tanta dificuldade com essa parte, o problema mesmo e que quando tento enviar o codigo para a controller ( estou fazendo em c#)  o campo 'imagem'  so recebe uma imagem,e eu gostaria de ter as três separadas. Vou postar o cidgo aqui.

Comment: @WilliamCézar Entendo... parece que no seu código em C# você não acessa os parâmetros do URL, ficou até mais fácil com uma função assim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não testei, vê se ajuda...

```
function NovaPublicacao() {

    var elem = document.getElementById("imagefiles");
    var images = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.files.length; ++ i) {
       images.push(elem.files[i].name);
    }
    var produtoData = {

        'Titulo': $('#produtoTitulo').val(),
        'Descricao': $('#produtoDescricao').val(),
        'Imagem': images[];
};
```

Comment: O seu metodo funcionou certinho , muito obrigado

Comment: unica coisa agora e que não estou conseguindo passar como Json , adicionei , fiz um nova pergunta , desculpe a quantidade de pergunta mais isso e tudo muito novo e preciso terminar este trabalho , você ajudou muito o meu entendimento sobre o funcinamento.
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152784/jquery-n%C3%A3o-passa-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-o-controller

Answer (score 1):

Então você quer passar várias imagens ao URL? Além de fazer isso, vai precisar percorrer cada uma no código ao lado do servidor.

Uma maneira de fazer isso é criar parâmetros no URL (ou POST) com um pré-fixo no ínicio do nome, por exemplo:

> ?Image0=&Image1=

E assim podemos guardar os dados de cada imagem em um parâmetro que começa com o pré-fixo "Image", com algum número ou nome na frente, sempre diferente do anterior.

Agora aqui vai um exemplo de implementação no seu código:

(Client-side)

```
/* cria o parâmetro de cada imagem */
for (var i = 0, files = $("#imagefiles")[0].files, f; f = files[i++];) {
    var reader = new FileReader
    reader.onload = function() {
        /**
         * this.result contém o conteúdo binário da imagem
         * criptografado com base64, com um
         * cabeçalho extra usado em URLs.
         */
        produtoData["Image" + i] = encodeURIComponent(this.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(f)
}
```

(Server-side)

Eu não entendo como o C# funciona para capturar parâmetros de URL, aliás nunca usei C# ao lado do servidor. Isso é um exemplo em PHP que pode ser facilmente convertido para C#.

```
<?php

/* atravessa cada parâmetro no URL */
foreach ($_POST as $url_param) {

    /* checa se começa o parâmetro começa com "Image" */
    if (substr($url_param, 0, 5) === "Image")

        /* possíveis dados */

        /* $_POST['Titulo'], $_POST['Descricao'], $url_param) */
}
```

Comment: Estou analisando seu código aqui , daqui a pouco eu volto , mas de qualquer forma muito obrigado.

Comment: @WilliamCézar Observação: o código em JavaScript seria inserido antes de chamar `jQuery.ajax`, pois o objeto `produtoData` teria sido modificado antes de ser mandado para lá. Re-veja o código do client-side, havia um erro de digito.

Comment: Eu estou pesquisando alguns métodos de C# para te dar um exemplo do server-side em C#

Comment: No caso esse metodo ajax chama a controler Produto/Publicar 
la se os parametros estiverem com o mesmo nome eu ja consigo usa-los noa controller , estou vendo seu codigo e vendo o que devo fazer, mas estou com certa dificuldade, já eu posto as minhas duvidas , mas muito obrigrigado pela atenção

Comment: vou tentar explicar a situação , quando eu do o post eu passo um JSON para a controller que eu coloquei no Ajax. mas o meu problema e utilizar fazer um vetor de imagem , ou simplesmente colocar 3 imagens em 3 variaveis diverentes>
tipo Imagem1 =  files[0]
      imagem2 = files[1]

Porque assim eu declaro os mesmo nomes na minha controler e la eu consigo salvar no banco.

Comment: O metodo do @MagicHat Resolveu , agora esta enviando um array com as string com a imagem , agora e so tratar no backend , muito obrigado pela sua ajuda .

Comment: @WilliamCézar Eu achei um método em C# agora, mas eu pensei que você queria o conteúdo binário da imagem. Você está passando o nome do arquivo, não o conteúdo da imagem... eu não sabia que era para pegar o nome :p

Comment: Para pegar o nome do arquivo da imagem basta indexar o objeto dela com "name"

Answer (score 1):

o método `.val()` do jQuery só retorna informações sobre o primeiro item de Arrays.

O input `file` contém a propriedade `files` do tipo `FileList`, que contém as informações das imagens selecionadas.

Itere sobre essa propriedade para preencher o `produtoData` do POST, e chame o $.ajax com opções para aplicar os padrões de processamento em cima do `produtoData` ao enviar a requisição:

```
var imageFiles = document.getElementById('imagefiles');

var produtoData = new FormData();

var files = document.getElementById('imagefiles').files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  produtoData.append('Imagem['+i+']', files[i]);
}

$.ajax({
  ...,
  processData: false,    // Não transforma ajaxData
  contentType: false,
  ...
});
```

Comment: Eu estou com dificuldade para enviar as informações com post , primeiro porque estava sem o processData e o contentData, e que você usa uma forma diferente de iterar o array, se puder respota esta pergunta :
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152784/jquery-n%C3%A3o-passa-informa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-o-controller